# CKEditor - image preview without uploading to server

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using Upload Image plugin to implement "drag drop to insert image" functionality. When I drop image into edit area, image is getting uploaded to server and then using the returned url to show preview.

But I need to show image preview in edit area without uploading to server. When I click on custom submit button I want save entire content including images to server.

Please let me know if anybody has done/any ideas on this.

Thanks in advance.

Siva

Answer (score 2):

That is pretty simple. `UploadWidget` is a helper to create content from dropped images: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.fileTools-method-addUploadWidget

There is the definition property `loadMethod` which can be `load` - which is exactly the option you need:
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.fileTools.uploadWidgetDefinition-property-loadMethod

Then, you can overwrite the upload image widget or create your own widget, based on the `fileReader` example from `UploadWidget`.

The code should look like:

```
CKEDITOR.fileTools.addUploadWidget( editor, 'imageReader', {
    loadMethod: 'load',
    supportedTypes: /image\/(jpeg|png|gif|bmp)/,

    fileToElement: function( file ) {
        var img = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( 'img' );
        img.setAttribute( 'src', loadingImage );
        return img;
    },

    onLoaded: function( loader ) {
        this.replaceWith( '<img src="' + loader.data + '" '>' );
    }
} );

// Black rectangle which is shown before the image is loaded.
var loadingImage = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDgAOAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAOAA4AAAIMhI+py+0Po5y02qsKADs=';
```

The only part which may not work is [notification](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_notifications) integration that listens on the upload event as far as I remember. If you need notifications, you need to add them manually.